# Can't connect to mysql through django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I had installed mysql and on python shell `import MySQLdb` does work. I also changed the settings.py as:

```
**DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
DATABASE_NAME = '/home/database/my_db.db'
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''    
DATABASE_PORT = ''**
```

but when I test for the connection it fails.

terminal:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
```

It gives the error as :

> OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql' (2)")

Comment: are you using xampp?, in that case try add username root. Name of the database looks wrong. And host should be localhost, if you are trying django locally. And `DATABASE_ENGINE` should look like this `ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql`.

Comment: @starcom: if it was a user/pass problem, it'd be permission denied, not "can't connect". Either mysql's not running, or python's looking for the socket in the wrong page. The space in `/var/run /mysql` in the error dump could be the cause. Probably should be `/var/run/mysql`

Comment: @MarcB: ah did not notice it.

Comment: still not working guys.... I have tried it already as Marc said. And just now I tried as starcorn told... Nothing works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django say its engine should be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#engine 'django.db.backends.mysql'

I think database name is the name of the database inside mysql not a path.  A path is just for sqlite.  Do you have mysql server running?
USER, PASSWORD are required.  host defaults to localhost port defualts to 3306.

Comment: Ya I did it by connecting to mysql: 
     $ mysql -u root -p  ## connecting mysql##
and changing settings.py as:
     DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
     DATABASE_NAME = 'my_db'
     DATABASE_USER = 'root'             
     DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'password'     
     DATABASE_HOST = ''             
     DATABASE_PORT = ''             

Here the database my_db is created from mysql as :
     mysql> CREATE DATABASE my_db.db

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a MySQL server? is it on:

- localhost (unix domain socket), or
- localhost (tcp), or
- localhost but not accessible, or
- some other host?

also, database name is name as mysql understands it, not a file path.

Comment: for django no need of local server. It just create the local host by: 
    sudo python manage.py runserver
in default port.

Comment: @Sujit absolutely false. You need to have MySQL running.

Comment: @Daniel and how can i do that if suppose i m using xampp or any suggested by you.